Find the Pulseaudio channel count
How can I check what the channel count is currently? I think I'm at 2 channels but I want to be able to confirm it. I'd like to be able to do it in the terminal with pactl if possible. Also how do I change this value? I run pulseaudio in system mode so I suppose I have to make changes to /etc/pulse/system.pa but I'm not sure what I should add.
I did try adding
load-module module-combine channels=10 channel_map=front-left,front-right
to the system.pa file but that did not seem to do anything to it.
Edit:  I assumed channel here refers to multiple devices (sinks).
